# Method chaining in Ada

Tags: oop, ada

So lots of languages have a pattern where you do something like this:

```
object = Create_Object().Set(1).Set(2).Set(3);
```

(I believe this originated in Smalltalk.) This works because the `Set()` method returns a reference to its receiver.

Can I do anything like this in Ada?

Approaches I've tried which don't work include:

```
-- doesn't work because the returned object is a read-only copy of the receiver
function Set(self: in out Object) return Object;

-- doesn't work because I can't return an access to a local variable
function Set(self: in out Object) return access Object;

-- looks like it works until I realise that it's not a method, and isn't doing
-- dynamic dispatch [*]
function Set(self: access Object) return access Object;
```

Can this be done?

Comment: [*] Rant follows: dynamic dispatch is painfully fragile in Ada; it is _so_ easy to accidentally break things in such a way that your code compiles cleanly and runs and then behaves weird because a method call is dispatching statically rather than dynamically. But that's not really relevant to my question...

Comment: Why would you want to return a reference to a private attribute?  That would leak access to internal state of the object.

Comment: Um, what private attribute?

Comment: Isn't that what Set returns?  You didn't specify what your code was supposed to do, so I had to guess.

Comment: Set returns a reference to its receiver (as stated in paragraph two).

Comment: And "the receiver" is the object Set operates on?

Comment: Apparently that terminology is less widespread than I thought; it was standard when I was taught all this stuff. It's from the 'objects receive messages' OO formalism which Smalltalk, Objective C, Ruby etc uses. I also see it used in Go, Python and Java; but there are lots of confused SO questions from Java people asking what receivers are, so go figure.

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen All three `Set` calls would return the same object (or access to object) as `Create_Object`; the effect would be that the `Set` functions would operate on the same object but would be chained together in one expression.  It's basically like "x := Create_Object(); x.Set(1); x.Set(2); x.Set(3);` but some people like the chaining syntax, and perhaps some think it's more readable.  There's no advantage other than that, though.

Comment: @DavidGiven The term "receiver" doesn't appear in the language specification at all for Java 7, except that it appears in the title of one example, without explanation.  (Java 8, introduced this year, did add a feature that involves the term.)

Answer (score 1):

I think a function with this profile will do the job for you:

```
function Set (Target   : in Instance;
              New_Item : in Integer) return Instance;
```

Having written a full package around that function declaration, I can write:

```
Object := Set (1).Set (2).Set (3);
Object.Show;
```

and get the output:

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

I've pushed the full sources to http://repositories.jacob-sparre.dk/miscellaneous-ada-2005-examples/.

Comment: I don't think it quite answers the question.  This does not cause `Set` to operate on the same object; rather, each `Set` copies the previous one into a temporary function-result object.  This may produce the same results if the new object is created by the expression, and if it's simple enough so that the copying process doesn't cause issues (no controlled subcomponents, e.g.).  But if `X` is an access to an existing object, `Something := X.Set(1).Set(2).Set(3)` will not operate on `X.all` which would be the desired behavior in the general chaining case.

Answer (score 1):

Your third proposal is the correct approach, and you are in fact defining a primitive operation when you type "access" for the parameter. Here is an example, which uses two tagged types to show where dispatching occurs, and uses chaining of method calls. I have provided a procedure for convenience, as well, since otherwise you would have to use a temporary variable. I have used Create_Object, but an explicit call to "new", but that's of course the same thing. In addition, I have shown an example where  Ada will not do dynamic dispatching when it knows statically the types involved. This is actually a nice features (performance-wise), even if indeed it requires care (and even experts are bitten every now and then :=)

```
with Utils; use Utils;    
procedure Chain is
   O : access Object := new Object;
   C : access Child := new Child;
begin
   O.Add (1).Add (2);
   C.Add (3).Add (4);
end Chain;

package Utils is    
   type Object is tagged null record;
   function Add (Self : access Object; Val : Integer) return access Object;
   procedure Add (Self : access Object; Val : Integer);  --  for convenience

   type Child is new Object with null record;
   overriding function Add (Self : access Child; Val : Integer) return access Child;
   overriding procedure Add (Self : access Child; Val : Integer);  --  for convenience
end Utils;

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;    
package body Utils is    
   function Add (Self : access Object; Val : Integer) return access Object is
   begin
      Put_Line ("func Object.Add" & Val'Img);
      Self.Add (Val);   --  static call, not dynamic dispatch
      return Self;
   end Add;

   procedure Add (Self : access Object; Val : Integer) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("proc Object.add" & Val'Img);
   end Add;

   overriding function Add (Self : access Child; Val : Integer) return access Child is
   begin
      Put_Line ("Child.Add" & Val'Img);
      Self.Add (Val);   --  static call, not dynamic dispatch
      return Self;
   end Add;

   overriding procedure Add (Self : access Child; Val : Integer) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("proc Child.Add" & Val'Img);
   end Add;   
end Utils;
```

The output of this program is:

```
func Object.Add 1
proc Object.add 1
proc Object.add 2
Child.Add 3
proc Child.Add 3
proc Child.Add 4
```

Edit: As discussed in the comments, it is recommended to always use overriding to make sure the procedure is indeed overriding, not using a different profile. An access parameter does create a primitive operation.

Comment: This doesn't work. A procedure on `access Object` isn't a method of `Object` and doesn't go in `Object`'s vtable --- so you never get dynamic dispatch at all. This was the approach I initially tried; I abandoned it when I realised that it was calling the wrong methods of all my objects. Here's an example: https://ideone.com/0Zn2ye Note that even though `o` is an access to a class-wide type, it's still statically calling `Superclass`'s `Method1()` rather than dynamically dispatching to `Subclass`'s version.

Comment: Of course a procedure on 'access Object', when declared in the same spec as the object, is a primitive operation and goes into the vtable. This is in fact the way the whole GtkAda library is organized.

Comment: The example I posted tries that and doesn't work. Can you expand?

Comment: Please post the actual code with object declaration (which your example does not have). The declaration of the subprogram must occur before the type is frozen, for instance (after which the vtable is no longer modified).

Comment: See the ideone link in my previous comment here. (I can't post code in a comment.)

Comment: I recommend to always use the Ada2012 "overriding" keyword, when you intend to override. In this case, GNAT will report that the Method1 for the subclass is not overriding. And that's because it returns aa Subclass.Ref, not a Superclass.Ref.

Comment: Fantastic --- that works: https://ideone.com/K9IwnJ If you want to update your answer to make it a bit clearer exactly what I was doing wrong, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From paragraph 18, function [formal] parameters can only use mode 'in' (read-only). So the input object does not get modified.

> 18 {parameter mode} The parameter mode of a formal parameter conveys the direction of information transfer with the actual parameter: in, in out, or out. Mode in is the default, and is the mode of a parameter defined by an access_definition. The formal parameters of a function, if any, shall have the mode in. [Ada 2005]

So I do not think that the language supports it as shown in other languages.

However, if you don't mind copies, we can save the result back in the object, but that's not the same as those other languages that you reference.

```
obj := obj.set("this").set(123).set(some_other_type);
```

You set "this" on a copy of 'obj' and return that copy. From that copy, we create a new copy and set 123 in that copy, which is in turn returned. Finally, that last result is copied and we set 'some_other_type' to it. That last copy is returned and we can save it in obj. Note that a well optimized implementation can avoid most if not all of those copies if the `set()` functions are small enough and inlined, but I would not could on it.

In retrospect, using procedures:

```
obj.set("this");
obj.set(123);
obj.set(some_other_type);
```

will do no copies at all.

Comment: In [Ada 2012](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-4-2.html), "functions … can have parameters of any mode."